# Calling content page event handler from master page button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am working on an asp.net application. I have a master page with search button. When user clicks search button, I want to go to search.aspx and call search button event handler on content page ( which is working as content page also has search functionality). How to call content page search button click on click of a button at master page ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not use the FindControl, and access the content page's control, cast it as button, and access the Click() event? That or I've misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option that you can do is expose an event from the master page that can be accessed in the content page. Accessing the EventArgs class should do the trick for you.

Content page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPageObject m = (MasterPageObject)base.Master;
    m.masterPageMethod += customMethod;
}
private void customMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your processing here
}
```

I'm accessing the master page's masterPageMethod here which should be bound to your click event.